# "Lorem ipsum" for non-Latin scripts?

Tags: text, internationalisation

[Lorem ipsum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) is the standard "placeholder" text for demonstrating typefaces or layouts in the Latin alphabet: it's got a relatively normal distribution of characters for a Western European language, but since it's nonsense, the user doesn't get distracted by trying to read it.

Are there similar placeholder texts for other scripts such as Cyrillic, or for languages such as Vietnamese that make heavy use of diacritics?

Comment: To be honest, I would close this question because it's answered with a simple search "lipsum [language name]" for any alphabet or language. The only downside is that you might need to translate the service's interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the text that is used is standard.  Even in a Latin script, it doesn't matter if your text is exactly the same as the standard *Lorem ipsum*, only that it looks like normal text while not making any real sense.

So the question then becomes, what text to use.  I've always found the [lipsum.com](http://lipsum.com) and [lorem-ipsum.info](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/) useful for this, as they generates valid looking text that makes no sense when you read it.  Between the two of them, you get coverage for most character sets that you're likely to need.

---

## Examples

#### Chinese

命医五事掲成医投六萩鋼日毎善四群。給社南変人持体求図感家午方特田集必。子展量能件室特無型旅稿千約文組目阪権次提。無琢山聞治宣世負再守皇写両派記。津謙年康出保実英重五育重査集都千台。地問法芸価供乳右帰朝全市。手柾事属選切女花申庫参織立町。得選変問事南載敗入康移以経物下困必載杯。作察自動升惑棋現時査覇奏莱立再出定暁的人。

#### Russian

Жят ыт жольюта льаорыыт. Ыльит компрэхэнжам ад мыа. Фачтидёе атоморюм конжтетуто нэ хаж, ед зюаз дылыктуч жят. Мыа ты пытынтёюм патриоквюы, эи дуо льаборэ рыкючабо. Ведят рыпудяары квуй ад. Эа омниюм анкилльаы элыктрам эож, нэ аффэрт лобортис адвыржаряюм нык.

#### Arabic

وترك يذكر حين بـ, فعل غريمه الخاصّة بـ, والمعدات ويكيبيديا، نفس إذ. ونتج الدّفاع من حدى, أي يكن دارت مهمّات, بزمام الشمال العناد فصل أم. أخر عن أحكم مهمّات السادس, تم طوكيو لتقليعة دون. عن مكثّفة اوروبا الإتفاقية تعد, جُل بـ مارد لهذه.

الأوضاع التخطيط في أضف, ومن جنوب أعمال الإتفاقية إذ, ولم الشهير التغييرات ان. ثمّة ونتج صفحة إذ عرض. ٣٠ يبق إحكام واقتصار التقليدي, الى كرسي والفلبين ان, منتصف وبداية و قبل. ٣٠ تمهيد السفن الأوروبية شيء. أطراف انتباه الأهداف كلا أم, الصفحة وبولندا الإنزال دون قد, الخارجية التجارية عدد عل.

(Please note here that this site doesn't handle RTL languages well, so the alignment is off with Arabic)

Comment: Жят ыт жольюта льаорыыт! As someone who can read Russian, I can't stop laughing at this gibberish.

Comment: @dnbrv At least we know that it doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Same goes for the Chinese. But hey that's what lorem ipsum is suppose to be. :)

Comment: I don't know about Chinese, @nightning, but I find this placeholder text incredibly distracting in Russian.